# Как нарисовать вписанную окружность

Tags: c#, winforms, графика

Нужно нарисовать правильный пятиугольник со вписанной окружностью так, чтобы получившаяся фигура поддавалась всем аффинным преобразованиям.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пятиугольник я нарисовал, перенос по OX и OY, масштабирование работают хорошо, но вот с окружностью возникли проблемы. Я попытался найти центр верхнего левого ребра пятиугольника, и от него рисовать окружность(пришлось подгонять, чтобы эллипс встал ровно), но потом понял что при преобразованиях будет беда, так как когда меняются размеры пятиугольника, размеры эллипса остаются неизменными. Так и вышло, пятиугольник преобразовывается нормально, а с окружностью проблемы.[image: фигура при переносе по OXY][image: Фигура при масштабировании]
Делаю я вот так

```
private void drawFigure(Graphics g, float[, ] matrixTrans)
        {            
            List<Point> p = new List<Point>();
            // Точки для пятиугольника.
            for (int i = 0; i < 360; i += 72)
            {
                double rad = (double)i / 180.0 * 3.14;
                int x = (int)(50 * Math.Cos(rad));
                int y = (int)(50 * Math.Sin(rad));

                p.Add(new Point(y, -x));
            }
            p = multiplicationMatrix(p, matrixTrans); // Умножение фигуры на матрицу преобразования.
            g.DrawPolygon(Pens.Red, p.ToArray());
            // Координаты средней точки верхнего левого ребра пятиугольника.
            float xMid = (p[0].X + p[4].X) / 2;
            float yMid = (p[0].Y + p[4].Y) / 2;
            g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, xMid - 16, yMid - 7, 78, 78); // Неуклюжая попытка нарисовать эллипс.             
        }
```

Как правильно нарисовать вписанную окружность относительно пятиугольника, чтобы можно было ее потом преобразовывать? Нужна какая то формула, или что то такое..

**---UPDATE 1---**

Получилось сделать масштабирование, делал вот так:

```
private void drawFigure(Graphics g, float[, ] matrixTrans)
        {            
            List<Point> p = new List<Point>();
            // Точки для пятиугольника.
            for (int i = 0; i < 360; i += 72)
            {
                double rad = (double)i / 180.0 * 3.14;
                int x = (int)(50 * Math.Cos(rad));
                int y = (int)(50 * Math.Sin(rad));
                p.Add(new Point(y, -x));
            }
            // Умножаю пятиугольник на матрицу преобразования
            p = multiplicationMatrix(p, matrixTrans);
            g.DrawPolygon(Pens.Red, p.ToArray());
            p.Clear();
            // Вычисляю точки прямоугольника для отрисовки эллипса
            p.Add(new Point((int)(-50 * Math.Cos(Math.PI / 5)), (int)(-50 * Math.Cos(Math.PI / 5))));
            p.Add(new Point((int)(50 * Math.Cos(Math.PI / 5)), (int)(50 * Math.Cos(Math.PI / 5))));
            p.Add(new Point((int)(-50 * Math.Cos(Math.PI / 5)), (int)(50 * Math.Cos(Math.PI / 5))));
            p.Add(new Point((int)(50 * Math.Cos(Math.PI / 5)), (int)(-50 * Math.Cos(Math.PI / 5))));
            // Умножаю прямоугольник на матрицу преобразования
            p = multiplicationMatrix(p, matrixTrans);
            // Вычисляю ширину и высоту прямоугольника для отрисовки эллипса
            float widthS = (float)Math.Sqrt((p[3].X - p[0].X) * (p[3].X - p[0].X) + (p[3].Y - p[0].Y) * (p[3].Y - p[0].Y));
            float heightS = (float)Math.Sqrt((p[2].X - p[0].X) * (p[2].X - p[0].X) + (p[2].Y - p[0].Y) * (p[2].Y - p[0].Y));
            g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red,p[0].X,p[0].Y, widthS, heightS);           
        }
```

Но теперь возникает проблема с другим аффинным преобразованием, с поворотом на угол.

Например я поворачиваю фигуру на 30 градусов. Пятиугольник поворачивается хорошо, но с эллипсом опять проблемы, он уезжает. Это происходит потому что координаты прямоугольника (в котором строится эллипс) поворачиваются, следовательно поворачивается левый верхний угол этого прямоугольника, и эллипс строится из него. Как это можно исправить?
[image: Неправильный поворот фигуры]

Comment: Поскольку при аффинном преобразовании общего вида окружность переходит в эллипс, то вовсе не факт, что после такого преобразования в пятиугольник всё ещё можно будет вписать окружность.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нужны только масштабирование и перенос, то достаточно преобразовывать вершины прямоугольника, ограничивающего окружность (эллипс), **по тем же законам, которые применяются к вершинам пятиугольника**.

Почему используется такая странная база `центр верхнего левого ребра` - мне непонятно, от центра пятиугольника вершины исходного квадрата будут отстоять на величину радиуса (a - длина ребра)

```
r = 0.5 * a / tg(Pi/5)
```

или через расстояние от центра до вершины (которое у вас 50)

```
r = R * cos(Pi/5)
```

Т.е. левая верхняя точка квадрата

```
new Point(-50 * cos(Pi/5), -50 * cos(Pi/5))
```

Для произвольных аффинных преобразований можно приблизить окружность кривыми Безье (как в общем и делается внутри графических библиотек) и преобразовывать их контрольные точки.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Высчитал левую верхнюю точку квадрата, нашел остальные точки квадрата, определил ширину и высоту и теперь эллипс строится хорошо. Масштабирование тоже заработало.

Comment: Возникла новая проблема, можете пожалуйста прочитать правки, которые я внес в вопрос? Вы хорошо разбираетесь в этой теме.

Comment: Используйте RotateTransform. [Пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32179702/draw-custom-ellipse-in-winform/32296022)

Comment: Видел эту функцию. А если делать без нее, то только используя кривые Безье? Другого способа нет?

Comment: А почему бы не пользоваться общей матрицей аффинного преобразования и для пятиугольника и для окружности? И не нужно будет точки вычислять.

Comment: Мне нужен факт умножения тела фигуры на матрицу аффинного преобразования. Если бы не это условие, я бы все преобразования делал через методы Matrix.

Comment: Ну так это же TransformPoints может делать